# How to add mininet module to pycharm?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, mininet

I'm trying to run a python code that imports mininet. I got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mininet.net'
```

I tried to add mininet from the interpreter but there are only ipmininet (which keeps fail in installing) and mininet-topology-yaml.
 Any idea how to solve this issue?
How I can add mininet to pycharm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably not a 'PyCharm' issue but rather an issue with your environment. Are you running this on a MiniNet VM? Is the package available when you run Python directly from the command line?

Comment: sorry but I'm really new to Linux, so can you simplify what you are aiming for?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu on a virtual machine and mininet is on the same VM

Comment: Have you gone through a basic 'getting started'? Are you running into any issues during that? https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. The PyCharm Python interpreter should be python 2 not any other version.

Someone may need this answer in the future!!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to correct the fact that the python 2 does not have to be used. For some reason, installing from packages only installs in the python 2 library directory and not python 3.
But when installing from source you can control this behavior.

To install mininet with python 3 directories, follow the official [installation guide from source](http://mininet.org/download/#option-2-native-installation-from-source), but before running the `install.sh` script, prefix it with the statement `PYTHON=python3`. So your installation command will be `PYTHON=python3 ./install.sh`

[Here's](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/bfc42f6d028a9d5ac1bc121090ca4b3041829f86/util/install.sh#L106) the line of code that checks what python version is installed